# Adding SQL constrained by python

Tags: odoo

so it's simple I get an error when adding a simple constraint (IdentationError: unexpected ident) that I added directly into postgres without problem

```
class fleet_site(osv.Model):

    _name = 'fleet.site'
    _description = 'Information du site'
    _order= 'name asc'
    _columns = {
        'name': fields.char('Nom', help='Nom du site', required=True),
        'vehicle_ids': fields.one2many('fleet.vehicle','site_id','Vehicules')
    }
        _sql_constraints = [('fleet_site_name_unique','unique(name)', 'Le nom du site existe')]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class fleet_site(osv.Model):

    _name = 'fleet.site'
    _description = 'Information du site'
    _order= 'name asc'
    _columns = {
        'name': fields.char('Nom', help='Nom du site', required=True),
        'vehicle_ids': fields.one2many('fleet.vehicle','site_id','Vehicules')
    }
    _sql_constraints = [('fleet_site_name_unique','unique(name)', 'Le nom du site existe')]
```

Python not allowed unidented code so you just need to manage equal spacing for eaxh block of code. I just removed extra spaces from your code.